# Twitter APIでTwitterアカウントのテーマカラーを変更するには？(PHP)

Tags: php, api, twitter

TwitterのAPIを使ったPHPプログラムで、アカウントのテーマカラーを変更させようと、

```
$request = $connection->post("http://api.twitter.com/1.1/account/update_profile.json", array("profile_link_color" => "606090"));
```

と書いたのですが、

```
object(stdClass)#3 (1) { ["errors"]=> array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#8 (2) { ["message"]=> string(31) "Sorry, that page does not exist" ["code"]=> int(34) } } }
```

とエラーが返されます。

書き方が間違っているのはわかるんですが、PHPもTwitterAPIもほとんど初めてで...具体的にどう書けばいいのかわかりません.

ご指導よろしくお願いします.

Comment: 1年以上前の質問ですが、解決したのであれば解決した内容を自己回答後承認してください。

Comment: @Myaku 了解です。失礼しました。

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[POST account/update_profile - プロフィール設定を変更する](https://syncer.jp/twitter-api-matome/post/account/update_profile)
を参考にして自己解決しました

Comment: "参考にした"だけじゃなく、どのようにしたか具体的に書いてください。その回答は削除されるかもしれません…

Answer (score 0):

コードを見る限りはURLのschemeのみが間違っているようです。`https` でアクセスしてください。(ただし、その場合には "SSL is required" のエラーメッセージが返ってくるはずです。)

エラーメッセージを見ると、URLそのものが間違っているようです。(`https` でアクセスはしている。) https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/post/account/update_profile を参考にして正しいURLを記載してください。

Comment: すみません。教えていただいたページでは、Resource URLは”https://api.twitter.com/1.1/account/update_profile.json”と書いてありましたが、その通りhttpsに変えても、やはり同じエラーで動きませんでした。公式のページでも、間違っているのでしょうか...